# mod_mono Not Serving up .aspx files Apach on Ubunutu

Tags: asp.net, apache, mod-mono

I have installed Apache web server on Ubuntu (16.04) and the repos have (Version 2.4.18).
I want run ASP.Net applications on the Web Server so I installed MONO as well.
Here is what I have done in this order:

1. sudo apt-get install apache2
2. sudo apt-get install mono-devel
3. sudo apt-get install referenceassemblies-pcl
4. sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-mono
5. sudo apt-get install mono-xsp4

Everything has installed successfully and  Apache doe serve of an index.html properly.

However when I try to view a .aspx file the web browser prompts me to download it. 
I thought that mod_mono was not configured, I then went to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled and both mod_mono.conf and mod_mono.load are there.
My mod_mono.conf is configured as:

> Include /etc/mono-server4/mono-server4-hosts.conf

I do not get any errors just prompted to download .aspx files.

I have already uninstalled MONO and Apache and reinstalled them with the same result.

Interestingly enough I have another Ubuntu machine that is the same build 16.04 I ran through the same steps and the .aspx files are served successfully. I even compared the files and structure between the two machines and they are the same.

Is there something that I a missing that could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After posting this I tried adding this line to my mod_mono.conf on my problem machine

> MonoAutoApplication enabled

Then restarted the Apache service
After that everything started working

Comment: Just tried Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS/Apache/mod_mono and this exact behavior (`MonoAutoApplication enabled` missing) was observed. Thank you for sharing!